# Delphi 10 - Carregar dados ao rolar listview para baixo

Tags: listview

Boa tarde!
Peço desculpas se este assunto estiver em discussão em outra área do fórum, mas passei muitas horas procurando por esta dica e não achei em lugar nenhum. Acabei descobrindo vasculhando as bibliotecas do listview.
O listview tem uma propriedade chamada PullRefresh. Até aí ta tudo certo, teoricamente, deveria funcionar, ao setar o ScrollViewPos para um valor negativo, vi em alguns lugares falando para coloca assim: ScrollViewPos < -40. Existe um video de um programador dedicado ensinando a modificar a unit FMX.Platform.Android.pas, pra mim funcionou bem até eu migrar para o Delhpi Tokyo, aí começou meu desespero, kkk.
Bom vamos ao que interessa, no IOs isso funciona sem problemas, mas no Android, vou dar a dica, no Android o ScrollViewPos nunca fica menor que zero, não entendi a razão, mas ele começa em 12 ou invés de zero, pra funcionar, faça o teste assim: 
if ScrollViewPos < 12 then
begin
seu codigo aqui
end;
Por mais incrível que pareça, é só isso.
Espero ter ajudado alguém com a dica
Fiquem na paz,
Eduardo Gomes.